# Orbit Jquery Plugin expand width to size of content without link

Tags: jquery, slider, orbit

I am using the Orbit Jquery Plugin from the ZURB Foundation and I was wondering if there was a way to auto-detect the width without having to include an `a href=""` link. As far as I can tell, the plugin detects the width from the `a` element and calculates width and height based on this. Is there a way to detect width and height without having to use an a element?

I put the code up on jsfiddle, though it is hardly functional there.

http://jsfiddle.net/jhoffm34/36vqb/1/

I'm still new to this, but wondering if there is a simple way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery, you can detect the width with [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

```
 var ratio=1/5; // 
 var height=$('img:first','#sliderfeatured').width()*ratio; // grab the first img width
 // or var height = $('img:first', '#sliderfeatured').attr('width')*ratio;
```